# trying to understand the tomcat hs_err_pid log

Tags: logging, crash, jvm

The following hs_err_pid.log was generated when my JVM crashed. I am trying to understand what caused it. Any input would be appreciated. Thank you.

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0e74c29e7d, pid=61623, tid=139695284021008
>
> JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.45-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>    Problematic frame:
>       V  [libjvm.so+0x4e5e7d]  java_lang_Throwable::set_backtrace(oopDesc*, oopDesc*)+0x4d
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>      http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x00007f0d7c017000):  JavaThread "catalina-exec-8080146" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=1342, stack(0x00007f0d57b7e000,0x00007f0d57c7f000)]

    siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000070

    Registers:
    RAX=0x00007f0d7c0097c0, RBX=0x00000006a3877f0c, RCX=0x00007f0e751cd7b0, RDX=0x0000000000000000
    RSP=0x00007f0d57c7a7b0, RBP=0x00007f0d57c7a7d0, RSI=0x00000006a3877f0c, RDI=0x00007f0e70031ca0
    R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x00007f0e751e23d8, R10=0x00007f0e751e6278, R11=0x00000000f429700a
    R12=0x00007f0e751e1790, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x00007f0d7c009ca0, R15=0x00007f0d7c017000
    RIP=0x00007f0e74c29e7d, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010297, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
      TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

    Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f0d57c7a7b0)
    0x00007f0d57c7a7b0:   00007f0d57c7a7d0 00007f0d7c0097b0
    0x00007f0d57c7a7c0:   00007f0d7c009ca0 00007f0d7c017000
    0x00007f0d57c7a7d0:   00007f0d57c7abf0 00007f0e74c2b3de
    0x00007f0d57c7a7e0:   00007f0d57c7a830 00007f0d57c7d920
    0x00007f0d57c7a7f0:   00007f0d57c7d8b8 00007f0d57c7d8b8
    0x00007f0d57c7a800:   00007f0d57c7a8f0 00007f0d57c7a8a0
    0x00007f0d57c7a810:   000000079fc46a40 00007f0d7c017000
    0x00007f0d57c7a820:   00007f0d7c009ca0 00007f0d57c7abd0
    0x00007f0d57c7a830:   00007f0d57c7a850 00007f0e6d000438
    0x00007f0d57c7a840:   0000000000000048 00007f0d7c017000
    0x00007f0d57c7a850:   00007f0d57c7ac70 00007f0e74c2b850
    0x00007f0d57c7a860:   00007f0d57c7a8f0 000b7f0e6d000438
    0x00007f0d57c7a870:   0101000000000000 00007f0e6e4e27d0
    0x00007f0d57c7a880:   0000000057c7aca0 00007f0d57c7a920
    0x00007f0d57c7a890:   0000040000000048 00007f0d7c009cd8
    0x00007f0d57c7a8a0:   00007f0d57c7d8b8 00007f0e6d000438
    0x00007f0d57c7a8b0:   00007f0e6d000310 00007f0d00000000
    0x00007f0d57c7a8c0:   00007f0d57c7d920 00007f0d57c7d8b8
    0x00007f0d57c7a8d0:   00007f0e6e4e2ae8 00007f0e0000000e
    0x00007f0d57c7a8e0:   00007f0e6e4e27d0 0000000000000000
    0x00007f0d57c7a8f0:   00007f0d57c7d8b8 00007f0e6d000438
    0x00007f0d57c7a900:   00007f0e6d000310 00007f0d00000000
    0x00007f0d57c7a910:   00007f0d57c7d920 00007f0d57c7d8b8
    0x00007f0d57c7a920:   00007f0d57c7d8b8 00007f0e6d000438
    0x00007f0d57c7a930:   00007f0e6d000310 00007f0d00000000
    0x00007f0d57c7a940:   00007f0d57c7d920 00007f0d57c7d8b8
    0x00007f0d57c7a950:   0000000000000115 00007f0e6d202d28
    0x00007f0d57c7a960:   000000000000017e 00007f0e6d202d28
    0x00007f0d57c7a970:   00000006a3877d98 000000060000017e
    0x00007f0d57c7a980:   00000006a3877d68 00000006a3877d98
    0x00007f0d57c7a990:   0000017ed470efa9 0000017800000006
    0x00007f0d57c7a9a0:   00007f0d57c7d8b8 00007f0e6d000438 

    Instructions: (pc=0x00007f0e74c29e7d)
    0x00007f0e74c29e5d:   8b 25 b5 9d 6e 00 48 63 f2 48 8d 1c 3e 49 8b 3c
    0x00007f0e74c29e6d:   24 83 7f 0c 01 74 0d 4c 8b 07 4c 89 ea 48 89 de
    0x00007f0e74c29e7d:   41 ff 50 70 31 c0 4d 85 ed 74 16 48 8b 15 49 86
    0x00007f0e74c29e8d:   6e 00 4c 89 ef 48 2b 3a 8b 4a 08 48 89 f8 48 d3 

    Register to memory mapping:

    RAX=
    [error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xb]

    Stack: [0x00007f0d57b7e000,0x00007f0d57c7f000],  sp=0x00007f0d57c7a7b0,  free space=1009k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    V  [libjvm.so+0x4e5e7d]  java_lang_Throwable::set_backtrace(oopDesc*, oopDesc*)+0x4d
    V  [libjvm.so+0x4e73de]  java_lang_Throwable::fill_in_stack_trace(Handle, Thread*)+0x5e
    V  [libjvm.so+0x4e7be9]  java_lang_Throwable::fill_in_stack_trace(Handle)+0x59
    V  [libjvm.so+0x54d99b]  JVM_FillInStackTrace+0xeb
    C  0x00007f0e7441a529  _fini+0xff451991

    Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
    J  java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace()Ljava/lang/Throwable;
    J  java.lang.Exception.<init>()V
    J  org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedTrace.init(Lorg/apache/commons/dbcp/AbandonedTrace;)V
    J  org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery()Ljava/sql/ResultSet;
    J  com.sanminasci.xto.dao.postgres.BusinessObjectDataDAOImpl.loadAttributesByBusinessObjectData(Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/BusinessObjectData;)Ljava/util/Map;
    J  com.sanminasci.xto.dao.postgres.BusinessObjectDataDAOImpl.findById(Ljava/lang/Integer;Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/BusinessObjectDefinition;)Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/BusinessObjectData;
    J  com.sanminasci.xto.dao.postgres.BusinessObjectDataDAOImpl.getSingleRelationshipBOData(Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/BusinessObjectData;Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/BusinessObjectRelationshipDefinition;)Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/BusinessObjectRelationshipData;
    J  com.sanminasci.xto.dao.postgres.BusinessObjectDataDAOImpl.getRelationshipsBOData(Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/BusinessObjectData;)Ljava/util/Map;
    j  com.sanminasci.xto.service.impl.BusinessObjectDataServiceImpl.getRelationshipsBOData(Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/BusinessObjectData;)Ljava/util/Map;+49
    J  com.sanmina.xto.std.recordDefect.MSILoadRepairMinorDescription.validateRepairMinorByPartNumberBusinessClass(Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/BusinessObjectData;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    j  com.sanmina.xto.std.recordDefect.MSILoadRepairMinorDescription.process(Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/BusinessObjectData;Lcom/sanminasci/xto/service/action/ServiceActionContext;)V+66
    v  ~StubRoutines::0x00007f0e6d000438
    J  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    J  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    J  com.sanminasci.xto.util.XtoHotDeployUtil.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    J  com.sanminasci.xto.presentation.web.ControllerManager.invokeRulexService(Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/Rule;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/BusinessObjectData;Lcom/sanminasci/xto/service/action/ServiceActionContext;Ljava/util/Set;Lcom/sanminasci/xto/dao/BusinessObjectDataDAO;)V
    j  com.sanminasci.xto.presentation.web.ControllerManager.invokeRulexService(Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/Rule;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/BusinessObjectData;Lcom/sanminasci/xto/service/action/ServiceActionContext;Ljava/util/Set;)V+7
    j  com.sanminasci.xto.presentation.web.ControllerManager.invokeRulexService(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sanminasci/xto/model/BusinessObjectData;Lcom/sanminasci/xto/service/action/ServiceActionContext;)V+25
    j  com.sanminasci.xto.presentation.web.ControllerManager.invokeRulexService(Lcom/sanminasci/xto/service/action/ServiceActionContext;)V+233
    j  com.sanminasci.xto.presentation.web.DynamicScreenEditionController.actionEvent(Ljavax/faces/event/ActionEvent;)V+44
    v  ~StubRoutines::0x00007f0e6d000438
    J  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    J  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    j  org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(Lorg/apache/el/lang/EvaluationContext;[Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+37
    j  org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(Ljavax/el/ELContext;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+27
    j  javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(Ljavax/faces/event/ActionEvent;)V+34
    j  javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(Ljavax/faces/event/FacesListener;)V+5
    J  javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(Ljavax/faces/event/FacesEvent;)V
    j  javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(Ljavax/faces/event/FacesEvent;)V+2
    j  org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(Ljavax/faces/event/FacesEvent;)V+2
    j  org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.broadcast(Ljavax/faces/event/FacesEvent;)V+69
    j  org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.broadcast(Ljavax/faces/event/FacesEvent;)V+69
    j  org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.broadcast(Ljavax/faces/event/FacesEvent;)V+69
    j  org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.broadcast(Ljavax/faces/event/FacesEvent;)V+69
    j  org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.broadcast(Ljavax/faces/event/FacesEvent;)V+69
    J  org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Lorg/ajax4jsf/event/EventsQueue;Z)V
    J  org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/event/PhaseId;Lorg/ajax4jsf/context/InvokerCallback;)V
    j  org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;)V+20
    j  com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;)V+46
    j  com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/lifecycle/Lifecycle;Ljava/util/ListIterator;)V+63
    J  com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;)V
    j  javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+98
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+376
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
    j  org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+42
    j  org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+31
    j  org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+301
    j  org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+305
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+119
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
    j  com.sanminasci.application.filters.FacesContextCheckFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+57
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+119
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+804
    J  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V
    j  org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+327
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+64
    j  com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat60AgentValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
    j  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+42
    j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V+158
    J  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Ljava/net/Socket;)V
    j  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Ljava/net/Socket;)Z+82
    j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run()V+25
    j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+66
    J  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V
    j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
    v  ~StubRoutines::0x00007f0e6d000438
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that it tried to access a non-mapped address (segmentation fault) in libjvm.so, i.e. JVM internals. Specifically the C++ method `java_lang_Throwable::set_backtrace` while trying to populate the stacktrace of an Exception object.

Those things usually are bugs within the JVM itself. Since you're still using java 6 which reached end of life I would suggest upgrading to a newer version to see if it has been fixed.